# Flask - Using the Same Variable in 2 Different Routes?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a user signup system where once clicking "Register," the site presents 2 forms: the first form is a typical user creation form with username, password, etc., and the 2nd form is a form with personal information, like age, birthday, etc.

Because the user could potentially leave before finishing their profile (personal info.), I don't want to actually create the user, i.e. add the username/password info. to the database, until both forms are submitted.

There is an instance of a `User` class created in the first form (`register()`) which needs to be added to the database, but this instance is created after submission of the first form.

So, my question is, is there a way to pass on the variable from the first page to the next?

Here's the code:

```
@app.route("/profile-creation/<username>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def profile_creation(username):
    form = ProfileForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # I would like to use the class "user" created in register() here.
        # The user class would be added and commited to a SQLite database.

        flash(f'You have successfully created your account!', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))

    return render_template('profile-creation.html', title = "Create Your Profile", form = form)


@app.route("/register", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')

        user = User(username = form.username.data, first_name = form.first_name.data, last_name = form.last_name.data,
        email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password)

        username = user.username

        flash(f'Please set up your profile to create your account.', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('profile_creation', username = username))

    return render_template('register.html', title = 'Register', form = form)
```

Essentially, how do I pass on the `user` instance created in `register()` onto `profile_page(username)`? I heard there's a way to do it with a session variable, but supposedly you're supposed to avoid those as much as possible. Is there a way to do it without it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the original username/password from the initial `/register` in `flask.session`. Then, when the user completes the rest of the setup, `/profile-creation`, the full input received can be committed to a database:

```
import flask 
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/profile-creation/<username>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def profile_creation(username):
   form = ProfileForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
       #get any other input fields here
       conn = sqlite3.connect('dbname.db').cursor()
       conn.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [flask.session['username'], flask.session['email'], flask.session['password'])
       #you can add additional columns to your actual database. The above is just an example
       conn.commit()
       conn.close()
       return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
   return render_template('profile-creation.html', title = "Create Your Profile", form = form)


@app.route("/register", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
  form = RegistrationForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
    user = User(username = form.username.data, first_name = form.first_name.data, last_name = form.last_name.data,
    email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password)
    username = user.username
    flask.session['password'] = hashed_password
    flask.session['username'] = user
    flask.session['email'] = email
    flash(f'Please set up your profile to create your account.', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('profile_creation', username = user))
  return render_template('register.html', title = 'Register', form = form)
```

`flask.session` stores whatever values are passed across the entire app, during the running of the `flask` builtin server.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, is ``type(flask.session['some_var'])`` always a string?

Comment: @LeetCoder No, the parameter passed to `flask.session.__getitem__` should be a string, but any type can be set as a value.